# How to show a page create with the view module in the administrative overlay?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I've created a view with the view module which is a kind of administative page and i'd like to show that page using the administrative overlay, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Showing a view in the overlay just requires you to implement [`hook_admin_paths_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths_alter/7.x).

```
function mymodule_admin_paths_alter(&$paths) {
  // Treat all user pages as administrative.
  $paths['the path of your view'] = TRUE;
}
```

Keep in mind this:

- In the path you can also use asterisks (e.g. node/*/edit), useful in the case the view is using contextual filters
- If the overlay is not accessible from the user, the page will be shown using the administrative theme, which could also be the default theme used by Drupal, if the site doesn't set a the administrative theme to be another one

Comment: I found this answer very useful, and went to use. I have the menu item in main-menu `/book-view` which is a link to one of view. so  in place of `'the path of your view'` I did place `'book-view'` But there is no change.  I did place `function` in template.php and replaced `mymodule` with `bartik`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I was looking for such feature for pdf file since long, suppose if I have pdf file link, so pdf file will open as overlay- same as seven theme?

Comment: It should be a path as defined in `hook_menu()` or `hook_manu_alter()` from a module. I am not sure it works for menu links like that. For file links, it doesn't work; you need a page that shows the file.